# Create Null Instance in Gstreamer 0.10

Tags: c#, .net, gstreamer

I **successfully** installed the ossbuild GStreamer to enjoy Gstreamer for C#.

The steps is summarized as following:

1. Download **GStreamer-WinBuilds-GPL-x86-Beta04-0.10.7.msi** and **GStreamer-WinBuilds-SDK-GPL-x86-Beta04-0.10.7.msi** from https://code.google.com/p/ossbuild/downloads/list (or you can download LGPL license pair which have less plugins supported)
2. Then install the former then latter.
3. Then you can find  the gstreamer-sharp .NET reference file,  **gstreamer-sharp.dll** located here:

   C:\Program Files (x86)\OSSBuild\GStreamer\version_variable\sdk\bindings\dotnet\gstreamer-sharp.dll
4. Another glue file, **gstreamersharpglue-0.10.dll**, needed to add inside the project and set it to Copy Always or Copy if Newer to make gstreamer-sharp works in Windows.

But when I tried to run the sample code (using Gst;) , it has exception.

```
var pipeline = new Gst.Pipeline();
//always have null instance here
var elementA = Gst.ElementFactory.Make("videotestsrc");
//exceptions happens
elementA["pattern"] = 18;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//must have
Gst.Application.Init();
var pipeline = new Gst.Pipeline();
//if don't have Gst.Application.Init(), it will always have null instance here
var elementA = Gst.ElementFactory.Make("videotestsrc");
//if no exceptions happens here then everything should be fine
elementA["pattern"] = 18;
```

if `Gst.Application.Init();` triggers error that cannot find python26.dll, solved by install [python 2.6](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.6/) and add python26.dll inside the project also.

Remember to initialize with `Gst.Application.Init();`, it costed me 2 days to solve null instance. Lastly since GStreamer and its bindings are compiled for the x86 architecture,so force your .NET assembly building for **x86**.